# Block search engines from the main domain while allowing add-on domains to rank well

Tags: seo, subdomain, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, noindex

I have a shared hosting account with a main domain and many add-on domains. I don't actually use the main domain, it just has a landing page.

Can I tell bots not to index the main domain WITHOUT effecting SEO of my add-on domains?

If so, how would I go about telling bots to ignore a whole domain?

Comment: Why don't want to index.

Comment: @user2434 Is this relevant?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a meta tag like `<meta name="robots" value="noindex">` in the head-area of the source code for that domain. This way bots can crawl the page and see the `noindex` hint.

If you put a *robots.txt* to disallow bots they will not crawl the site, but still have parts of it in the search index.